# Windows does not come back into hibernation after booting to another Windows

Tags: windows, hibernate, bootable-media

I have Windows 11 installed on a partition of my computer. I also have Windows 11 and Ubuntu installed on a USB drive.

Sometimes I will put the Windows 11 on the computer to hibernation then boot up the USB drive. If I go into Ubuntu, when I come back to the Windows 11 on the computer will restore from hibernation perfectly fine. But if I go into Windows 11 on the USB drive, when I come back the Windows 11 on the computer will start anew, which is not a good thing as all the data will be lost.

Can anybody tell me why this happens and is there any way to change this behaviour?

Comment: Linux can leave partitions alone. Windows cannot. This corrupts the hibernated state.

Comment: Do you mean a USB stick or a USB drive?